# how to make seprate login for the admin and others in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i need to make two different login for other users and admin. 
i have made two different login controller. For admin i tried to override attemptLogin function

AdminLoginController.php

```
 public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {

        $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        $admin = $user->hasRole('admin');

        if($admin){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

but this make user logged in for both the users admin as well as other user. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create seperate routes for different user roles like  `http://yoursite.com/admin`  and `http://yoursite.com/customers`

Comment: yes i  have made different routes.

Comment: i just  want to prevent other users to login via admin login

Comment: I have added a working code , But it is in mongodb, You can adjust the query accordingly by checking the roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {

        $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        $admin = $user->hasRole('admin');

        if($admin){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $this->guard()->logout();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Okay you did the same logic like forcing logout for wrong role Isnt it ?

Comment: yes! i did'nt find any way to prevent user to logged in.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do a checking for that inside your login action of admin as given below, I am sharing the code which I have used in one of my project. I hope you can understand, i have added comments also

```
public function login(Request $request){
    if(auth()->user()){
        $user = auth()->user()->toArray();
        $role = Role::where('_id', new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($user["role_id"]))->first(); 
        if($role) $role = $role->toArray();
        if(!empty($role)){
            // Prevent other users to enter admin area by checking the role
            if(strtolower($role['name']) != 'admin'){
                Auth::logout();
                \Session::flash('errors', 'You are not authorized to access admin area.' );
                return redirect(url('/admin/login'));   
            }else{
                return redirect(url('/admin')); 
            }


        }else{
            Auth::logout();
            \Session::flash('errors', 'Invalid user role' );
            return redirect(url('/admin/login'));
        }   
    }
    return view('admin/index/login');   
}
```

If any users other than admin try to login in admin area, by checking the role force them to logout the system

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to define new guard and provider in `config/auth.php`.

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [ // default guard
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]
    ],
```

App/Admin.php class is your admin eloquent class and App/User.php is your user eloquent class. This way assumes that admins and users have got separated table in database. Of course you should also use admin guard in your AdminLoginController by one of two ways:

- set `protected $guard = 'admin';`
- set `public function guard(){
          Auth::guard('admin');
      }`